# regular expression to add characters before and after numbers

Tags: regex, numbers, expression, notepad++, character

I have a list of numbers between square brackets, and I need to add words before and after the exact numbers (i.e. keep the same numbers).  I use notepad++ to replace, but if you have a solution with other program please advise.

Example:

```
text [121] othertext
moretext [16] othertextmore
andtext [5940] othertextplus
```

outcome:

```
text xxxxxxxxx [121] xxxxxxxxx othertext
moretext xxxxxxxxx [16] xxxxxxxxx othertextmore
andtext xxxxxxxxx [5940] xxxxxxxxx othertextplus
```

The numbers are of course `\d+` but I want to tell it to keep the same numbers when looking.

Comment: While the regex sill stay the same, the code will change: WHich Language?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Find What:  `(\[\d+])`

Replace With: `xxxxxxxxx \1 xxxxxxxxx`

[image]

Comment: @Mike - You can accept as answer by clicking on the tick on the left.

Comment: No need for parentheses if you're going to use the entire match anyway - replace with `xxxxxx \0 xxxxxx`.

Comment: Really? Interesting but not surprising given Notepad++'s lackluster regex support.

Comment: don't forget to put your search statement into parenthesis

Answer (score 5):

Regular expression:

```
Find regex = \[\d+\]
Replace regex = xxxxxxxxx$&xxxxxxxxx
```

Refer: [regexr](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 2):

C#:

```
line=Regex.Replace(line,@"([^\[])(\[\d+\])(.*)","$1xxxxxxxxx $2 xxxxxxxxx$3");
```

Other languages analogous