# How to insert before and after a pattern in notepad++ with regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big txt file ,with many strings ,say "string-I-want-to-change",now I need to change all of them into this :

```
string-insert-before-string-I-want-to-change-string-insert-after
```

I mean ,find a pattern ,insert something before and after the pattern ,but just keep the pattern.I tried many ways ,they just replaced the pattern with the string I want to insert.

I tried the method here
[Using RegEX To Prefix And Append In Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283608/using-regex-to-prefix-and-append-in-notepad)

and here

[regular expression to add characters before and after numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624018/regular-expression-to-add-characters-before-and-after-numbers)

But they seem do not work with my version of notepad++,I am using the newest version 6.1.2

Some one please help me :)
Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide an example input and output and the code you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you.

`find : (string-i-want-to-change)`

`replace : string-in-front-of-it-\1-string-after-it`

test string :

`other-strings-came-in-front-of-it-string-i-want-to-change-and-it-continues-like-that`

output :

`other-strings-came-in-front-of-it-string-in-front-of-it-string-i-want-to-change-string-after-it-and-it-continues-like-that`